# $\chi(G - u-v) = \chi(G) -2,$ for any two vertices $u$ and $v$ then the graph is complete.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a graph with the property that on the deletion of any two vertices from the graph the chromatic number of the graph decreases by $2$, i.e.
$$\chi(G - u-v) = \chi(G) -2,$$ for any two vertices $u$ and $v$. We have to prove that the graph $G$ is none other than a complete graph.

I tried starting with the graph $G -u-v$. Then adding a vertex should increase the chromatic number by $1$. I am stuck here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that there is an edge between every pair of vertices. For contradiction, suppose that this is not the case for some $u,v$. Then from any valid coloring of $G - u - v$ with $k$ colors you can get a coloring of $G$ with $k+1$ colors by coloring $u$ and $v$ with the same new color. This shows that $\chi(G) \leq \chi(G-u-v) + 1$, a contradiction.